# Audio reverts to S/PDIF

Tags: sound, 16.04

on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I have no audio.

My laptop is a HP Compaq CQ58-390SI and under audio I have only the option of Digital Output (S/PDIF) Built-in Audio. No other option of changing to the internal speakers.

When I connect to my HDTV everything is fine but when I disconnect and even reboot, no audio??